# How to get custom attributes of User using Admin Sdk?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-admin-sdk

I am using the Admin SDK 1.8.2, I am able to get the user details except birthday,gender and custom attributes in Java.
 https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/get.
 https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users.
Is there any way to get custom attributes,birthday etc details..?
At least I have to retrieve custom attributes and Birthday.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48912906/retrieve-custom-attribute-from-user-profile-in-google-api-scripts-google-admin