# Retrieve custom attribute from user profile in Google API Scripts- Google Admin Directory

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

This is about G suite users.The following works in Google Admin Directory using Google Admin SDK. It retrieves email address and full name of user.

```
var myemail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  var mycontact = AdminDirectory.Users.get(myemail);
  var myname = mycontact.name.fullName;
```

There is a custom attribute in user profile named "Department". The following does NOT retrieve anything. It throws null

```
var mydept = mycontact.Department;
```

How can one retrieve custom attribute from user profile in G suite?

Comment: I'm curious if  you got it working. Did my answer do the trick or did you find another way?

Answer (score 6):

According to [Directory Api - Users: get](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/get) you need to set the `projection` to `"custom"`.

> **projection** - What subset of fields to fetch for this user.
>
> Acceptable values are:
>
> "basic": Do not include any custom fields for the user. (default)
>
> "custom": Include custom fields from schemas requested in customFieldMask.
>
> "full": Include all fields associated with this user.

Then you should define a [Schema](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-schemas) for the custom data

> **customFieldMask** (string) A comma-separated list of schema names. All fields from these schemas are fetched. This should only be set when projection=custom.

**So something like:**

```
var mycontact = AdminDirectory.Users.get({
  "userKey": myemail,
  "projection": "full",
  "customFieldMask": "Define Schema Here"
});
```

You can then `Logger.log(mycontact);` to see how to access the returned custom fields

Comment: Thanks for this solution! Had to modify syntax for it to work for me: email should be outside the json. e.g., for all parameters, including custom schemas: `var mycontact = AdminDirectory.Users.get( myemail, {"projection": "full"});`

Answer (score 0):

For a custom schema, you can just use the `full` projection to get all custom schema fields.

For the standard department field, see `user.organizations[0].department`

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users

Answer (score -1):

If you got an error :

> Resource Not Found: userKey

Try this :

```
mycontact = AdminDirectory.Users.get(
  myemail,{
  projection: 'full'
});
```