# Retrieving values from customSchemas in Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk

In a Google Workspace for Education environment I want to work with a customSchema in the user's profile in order to automate some administrative tasks.

Suppose I have made a customSchema called "housing" in the admin backend.
Within "housing" I have made an item "rooms", which contains the value "4".

I succeeded already in retrieving all the user's profile information. The output (`Logger.log...`) indeed contains the customSchema.
Retrieving a fullName or a givenName from the profile is no problem either.

This is my working code so far.

```
function myTryout() {
  // code needs import of service = Admin SDK
  var myEmailAdress = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  // INFO = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48912906/retrieve-custom-attribute-from-user-profile-in-google-api-scripts-google-admin 
  var iAm = AdminDirectory.Users.get(myEmailAdress);
  var myName = iAm.name.fullName;
  Logger.log("USER'S FULL NAME = " + myName);
  allMyData = AdminDirectory.Users.get(myEmailAdress,{projection: 'full'});
  Logger.log("ALL USER'S DATA = " + allMyData);
}
```

However, accessing the data from customSchemas doesn't seem as straightforward.

So what is the code to extract the value for "rooms" from a user's data?
And what is the code to write (or overwrite) this value from a user's data?

`Logger.log("ALL USER'S DATA = " + allMyData)` shows me all available data in the user's profile:

```
{"thumbnailPhotoEtag":"\"3mhkESrZKxFccxpwig0yxvrUnxZYMxZUQujDNbVwMy4/jqzjWbJaD1m-N5bWVFSSTQ59Rr8\"","primaryEmail":"a_teacher@babotaniek.be","id":"112697199011841056502","emails":[{"address":"a_teacher@babotaniek.be","primary":true},{"address":"a_teacher@babotaniek.be.test-google-a.com"}],"orgUnitPath":"/","customerId":"C04agxt6k","agreedToTerms":true,"isEnrolledIn2Sv":false,"isMailboxSetup":true,"name":{"givenName":"a","familyName":"teacher","fullName":"a teacher"},"kind":"admin#directory#user","isDelegatedAdmin":false,"isAdmin":false,"etag":"\"3mhkESrZKxFccxpwig0yxvrUnxZYMxZUQujDNbVwMy4/oVtc4zE6rVvNCi4C8ycs-g15wqw\"","archived":false,"creationTime":"2018-09-06T20:19:55.000Z","ipWhitelisted":false,"changePasswordAtNextLogin":false,"isEnforcedIn2Sv":false,"lastLoginTime":"2022-02-15T11:27:05.000Z","nonEditableAliases":["a_teacher@babotaniek.be.test-google-a.com"],"customSchemas":{"babotaniek":{"aantal_km_met_de_fiets_heen_en_terug":6,"rijksregisternummer":"76798732544","stamboeknummer":"67867547567865","rekeningnummer":"FR798757654877658"},"housing":{"rooms":6,"sinks":7}},"languages":[{"preference":"preferred","languageCode":"nl"}],"thumbnailPhotoUrl":"https://www.google.com/s2/photos/private/AIbEiAIAAABECPa96Lmo5-CasAEiC3ZjYXJkX3Bob3RvKig4YjcxMDRhNzBiNmZkNDRiM2E3MmZjNzk3OTAzNGY0NTkyMTM2MmVhMAEsJu9fD0gMXnysdJsU_77BAHnQgQ","includeInGlobalAddressList":true,"suspended":false}
```

Note that the customSchemas and the values therein are listed.

If you're so kind to answer my question, please keep in mind that I'm rather new to coding. I didn't understand the few things I found on the web, so please give an answer suitable for dummies.

Comment: Can you share a sample of your code ?

Comment: I have added the code that works so far. I get all the user's data with it but cannot single out the values in the customSchema in my domain.

Comment: Reference :https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users    You should be able to get customSchemas from allMyData return(if this throw no errors). Use update methods to overwrite the existing data.

Comment: what's the response you get in `allMyData`

Comment: This is the response I get in allMyData when I use it with a dummy account. Note that the customSchemas and the values therein are listed > shorturl.at/nyzI4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem appeared to be very straightforward.

```
function thisWorks() {
// code needs: import of service = Admin SDK
// code needs predefined customSchema 'housing' with item 'rooms'
var myEmailAdress = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(); //e-mailaddress of current user
var iAmAll = AdminDirectory.Users.get(myEmailAdress,{projection: 'full'}); // ALL USER DATA of current user, including customSchemas
var testCustom = iAmAll.customSchemas.housing.rooms;
Logger.log("TESTING = " + testCustom);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you only want to retrieve the data within a specific Custom Schema, in this scenario you can make use of the standard resource `Fields` where you can specify which value you want returned. So if you are looking to only retrieve the specific custom schema data you can use this code:

```js
function myTryout() {
  // code needs import of service = Admin SDK
  var myEmailAdress = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  // INFO = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48912906/retrieve-custom-attribute-from-user-profile-in-google-api-scripts-google-admin 
  var iAm = AdminDirectory.Users.get(myEmailAdress);
  var myName = iAm.name.fullName;
  Logger.log("USER'S FULL NAME = " + myName);
  allMyData = AdminDirectory.Users.get(myEmailAdress,{fields: 'customSchemas',projection: 'Custom',customFieldMask: 'rooms'});
  Logger.log("Custom SChema data = " + allMyData);
}
```

I modified your code a bit so it will display only the information of one specific Custom Schema, if you want to retrieve all the values in all Custom Schemas, change `projection` to Full and delete the `CustomFieldMask` as this searches through specific schemas. You can check it out and test it using the [Users.get](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/get) first so you can have an idea.

Now if what you want is to overwrite the data within the customSchema you can make use of [users.update](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/update) following the same logic by modifying the `Fields` resource.

Comment: Either I don't get it or there is something wrong with the code.
The line allMyData = ... gives me the following error: GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to directory.users.get failed with error: Invalid Input: [rooms]

Comment: Still I think we're not far from the solution.

Comment: [rooms] was just an example, the customFieldMask is the value of the customSchema that you want to retrieve, so if the customSchema data that you want to retrieve is called `AWS` then that's the name that you should use instead. In your case `housing` should return values added in rooms.

Comment: We're almost there.

Comment: Almost there.
AdminDirectory.Users.get(myEmailAdress,{fields: 'customSchemas',projection: 'Custom',customFieldMask: 'housing'});
gives me this:
{"customSchemas":{"housing":{"sinks":3,"rooms":4}}}
Now I still don't get how to retrieve the value "4" from "rooms". Can you point out this last step for me? (Sorry to be a nuissance. I'm a total newbie in this.)